# How to retrieve the color of a cell in Excel?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have tried many possibilities. But i am not able to retrieve the exact color.
Apache POI version: 4.0.1

Below are some examples.

```
row.getCell(0).getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundXSSFColor().getARGBHex()
```

Output: null for every color.

```
row.getCell(0).getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColor()
```

Output: 64 for every color

```
row.getCell(0).getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColor()
```

Output: 0

```
row.getCell(0).getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColorColor()
```

Output: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor@4813bcba

```
row.getCell(0).getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor()
```

Output: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor@c04a46bb

Comment: Selenium has nothing to do with excel.

Comment: Hi Ramakarishnan check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39667614/get-cell-colour-with-apache-poi

Comment: What is wrong with the result from `row.getCell(0).getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColorColor()`? Is it the wrong color?

Comment: @SteffenJacobs I am not sure what this (org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor@4813bcba) color is.

Comment: It is a class XSSFColor. You can do `XSSFColor color = row.getCell(0).getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColorColor();` and then for example `color.getARGB()` to get a byte array with the alpha-red-green-blue values of the color.

Comment: @SteffenJacobs I used as you suggested.
XSSFColor color= row.getCell(0).getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColorColor();    
   System.out.println("col= "+color.getARGB());
The output is Null.

Comment: @uness ITs not working

Comment: @Guy Thanks. Can you please suggest any solutions?

Comment: Try `.getRGB()` instead of `.getARGB()`

Comment: Have you tried checking the Foreground colours too? Excel is a bit strange in what it does a foreground and what it does as background....

Comment: @SteffenJacobs Still it is throwing null. But without using getRGB() the output is as follows:
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor@4813bcba

Comment: @Gagravarr I have tried both foreground and background. I am not getting the expected output.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39667614/get-cell-colour-with-apache-poi. I have just tested my answer there and updated for current `apache poi` versions. Works for me.

Comment: @AxelRichter May I know where can I get the exact color equivalent to those hex got from output?

Comment: What do you mean with "the exact color equivalent"? Do you mean a [java.awt.Color](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)? Or something else?

Comment: @AxelRichter I have filled yellow color in (0,0) cell. When I searched for the output hex in color picker it is showing as white color. So I am not sure sure whether my code is wrong or the color picker.

Comment: I do not understand your last comment. You mean the color picker in `Excel`'s GUI shows white instead of yellow although the cell has a yellow fill color set? I never heard about this problem nor had I had this problem unti now. But this is a `Excel` issue then and not a `apache poi` issue. Sure the yellow fill color is not because of conditional formatting? Conditional formatting is a total other kind of thing.